# How can I list the contents of all the <p> elements in the console using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to log the content of all the `<p>` elements in the console by pressing on a button here is the code so far.

```
window.addEventListener("load",init);
function init(){

        var b = document.getElementById("btn2")
        b.addEventListener("click",action)
}
function action(){
    var i, items = document.qetElementsByTagName("p");

    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {


        console.log(items[i]);

    }
}
```

Comment: `console.log(items[i].innerHTML);` or `console.log(items[i].textContent);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get content using **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** or **[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** property

```
console.log(items[i].innerHTML); 
//or
console.log(items[i].textContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

(Plain JavaScript)
To list all "p" use

`console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("p"))`

Or use for first "p" only

`//console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0])`

To get content of first "p"

`console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].textContent)`

Comment: OP wants to log the *content* of the `<p>`.